# ul is not defined at HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando o código abaixo, mas recebendo um erro

```
function readyDom(callback) {
    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
        callback();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    }
}
readyDom(function() {
    var navbar = document.createElement("style");
        ul.innerHTML = 'body { margin: 0; } ul.spot-nav { list-style-type: none; font-family: Verdana; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background-color: #333; } li.spot-li { float: left; } li.spot-li a.spot-a { display: block; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 14px 16px; text-decoration: none; }';
    document.head.appendChild(navbar);
});
readyDom(function() {
    var segundos = 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.className = "spot-nav";
        ul.innerHTML = '<li class="spot-li">' +
                          '<a class="spot-a" href="https://grupospotlight.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.grupospotlight.com/assets/img/logo-nav-inverse.png" draggable="false" width="100"></a>' +
                          '</li>' +
                          '<li class="spot-li" style="float: right; padding-top: 3px;">' +
                          '<a class="spot-a" href="https://grupospotlight.com" target="_blank">WWW.GRUPOSPOTLIGHT.COM</a>' +
                          '</li>';
        document.body.insertBefore(ul, document.body.firstChild);
    }, 1000 * segundos);
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muda `ul.innerHTML = 'body...` para `navbar.innerHTML = 'body...`.

`ul` não está acessível no escopo dessa função anónima, e no fundo o que queres é adicionar esse CSS ao elemento `style` (`navbar`) que vais adicionar à página certo?

```js
function readyDom(callback) {
    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
        callback();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    }
}
readyDom(function() {
    var navbar = document.createElement("style");
    navbar.innerHTML = 'body { margin: 0; } ul.spot-nav { list-style-type: none; font-family: Verdana; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background-color: #333; } li.spot-li { float: left; } li.spot-li a.spot-a { display: block; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 14px 16px; text-decoration: none; }';
    document.head.appendChild(navbar);
});
readyDom(function() {
    var segundos = 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.className = "spot-nav";
        ul.innerHTML = '<li class="spot-li">' +
            '<a class="spot-a" href="https://grupospotlight.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.grupospotlight.com/assets/img/logo-nav-inverse.png" draggable="false" width="100"></a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '<li class="spot-li" style="float: right; padding-top: 3px;">' +
            '<a class="spot-a" href="https://grupospotlight.com" target="_blank">WWW.GRUPOSPOTLIGHT.COM</a>' +
            '</li>';
        document.body.insertBefore(ul, document.body.firstChild);
    }, 1000 * segundos);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

creio que o problema seja aqui:

```
readyDom(function() {
    var navbar = document.createElement("style");
        ====>>> ul.innerHTML = 'body { margin: 0; } ul.spot-nav { list-style-type: none; font-family: Verdana; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background-color: #333; } li.spot-li { float: left; } li.spot-li a.spot-a { display: block; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 14px 16px; text-decoration: none; }';
    document.head.appendChild(navbar);
});
```

você está tentando acessar essa variável ul que não foi declarada na função. você declarou na terceira função que postou acima.

tente unir as duas funções em uma. isso deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Não entendo de javascript, teria como fazer isso pra mim?

Comment: primeiro me explique pra que serve cada uma das tres funcoes que voce postou